# Proof involving partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Prove that for fixed positive integers k and n, the number of partitions of n is equal to the number of partitions of 2n+k into n+k parts.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What did you try, where are you getting stuck? Please update the question with your own work/ideas/progress, and we will be happy to guide you further. Here, for example, it may help to exhibit a transformation, showing the correspondence.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please do not pose the same question twice.  If you are not satisfied with the answer you receive, edit the original question to clarify what you have done, where you are stuck, and what help you need.